# Android: HomeScreen

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, homescreen

I'm currently developing a simple android `HomeScreen` with just 1 page.
I would like to know how to enable my `HomeScreen` to run and display widgets like [this](http://www.appbrain.com/app/3d-digital-weather-clock/factory.widgets.ThreeDDigitalWeatherClock) free widget.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: See this. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Comment: And this also. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm currently browsing the mentioned articles and it seems to be that they are guidelines on how to make a widget. I actually wanted to use or display existing widgets on my own HomeScreen. But I will still finish reading these articles. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way you can use it, just get sources of Launcher application and find how AppWidgetHost added to view hierarchy and how it is maintaining AppWidgetHostView instances.
Launcher sources you can get here:
[Laucnher.git](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher.git;a=summary)

Answer (score 0):

The home screen widgets are added by users based on the free-space they have and where they want the widget to be placed in their home-screen. As a developer you can only provide a widget, but adding that to the home-screen is purely in the control of the user.